# MongoDB - set nested field using name from variable

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I want to create new field in my document, lets call it `"shelf"`, it will be an object.
Next I want to make two `$set` operations - I want to put arrays named `"Tom"` and "Anna" into my `"shelf"`.

The problem is that I can't match correct query to do that.

I'm using nodejs MongoDB driver.

```
var myid = 'Tom-Anna'
var TomArray = ["Tom"]
var AnnaArray = ["Anna"]

await db.collection('people').updateOne(
        { pairid: myid },
        { $set: { shelf: TomArray } },
        { upsert: true }
      )

await db.collection('people').updateOne(
        { pairid: myid },
        { $set: { shelf: AnnaArray } },
        { upsert: true }
      )
```

Finally, the `"shelf"` document containing only `"AnnaArray"`, because it's overwriting previously added `"TomArray"`.

I can't add `"Tom"` and `"Anna"` array to `"shelf"` at the same time because content of arrays are generated separately.

I was trying this code:

```
var name = 'Tom'
var array = ['Tom']
await db.collection('people').updateOne(
        { pairid: myid },
        { $set: { shelf[name]: array } },
        { upsert: true }
      )
```

But it's throwing following error:

> { $set: { shelf[name]: array } },
>                         ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

My goal is to set my field like JSON:

```
"shelf": { "Tom": ["Tom"], "Anna": ["Anna"] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to specify nested key name:

```
var name = 'Tom'
var array = ['Tom']
db.people.update({ pairid: 1 }, { $set: { [`shelf.${name}`]: array } })
```